# How to post facebook auth data json to mongodb using facebook javascript SDK

Tags: node.js, facebook, mongodb, parsing, express

**My code is here, i am working with node js, express, mongodb and parse server**

*I don't know how to ask exact question for this problem but i hope some one will help me!! Thank you in advance.*

> logInWithFacebook = function() {
>               FB.login(function(response) {
>                   if (response.authResponse) {
>                       alert('You are logged in & cookie set!');
>                       var access_token = FB.getAuthResponse()
>   ['accessToken'];
>                       // console.log('Access Token = ' + access_token);
>
> ```
>                 var set = response.authResponse;
>
>                 FB.api('/me', function(response) {
>
>                     $.ajax({
>                         url: '/parse/classes/_User',
>                         type: 'POST',
>                         contentType: 'application/json',
>                         data: JSON.stringify({
>                             'authData': {
>                                 'facebook': {
>                                     'id': set.userID,
>                                     'access_token': set.accessToken,
>                                     'expiration_date': set.expiresIn
>                                 }
>                             }
>
>                         }),
>
>                         success: function() {
>                             console.log('dfjsf')
>                         },
>                         dataType: 'json'
>                     });
>                     console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
>                 });
>
>                 // Now you can redirect the user or do an AJAX request to
>                 // a PHP script that grabs the signed request from the cookie.
>             } else {
>                 alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
>             }
>         });
>         return false;
>     };
>     window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
>         FB.init({
>             appId: '798106123623614',
>             cookie: true, // This is important, it's not enabled by default
>             version: 'v2.2'
>         });
>     };
>
>     (function(d, s, id) {
>         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
>         if (d.getElementById(id)) {
>             return;
>         }
>         js = d.createElement(s);
>         js.id = id;
>         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
>         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
>     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
> </script>
>
> <div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="true" data-auto-logout-link="true"></div>
> ```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? It is easier for people to help you out if you can point out exactly what the issue is.

Comment: the problem is i m not able to save user information in database while sign up or login using facebook javascript SDK.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: it shows 403 forbidden status code in console while trying post data to node server using ajax post method.

Comment: That error code tells you what's going on. If you look for it you will see that it means the server understands the request correctly but is configured to deny access. So you will most likely need to look into the server config, or maybe the access token is incorrect/invalid.

Comment: Actually, its Solved. I used custom header beforeSend() in ajax request. and set the correct appId.
Thanx for your support  Acapulco.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
                                url: 'http://localhost:1337/parse/users',
                                type: 'POST',
                                ***beforeSend***: function(xhr) {
                                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", '***appId***');
                                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", 'application/json');
                                },

                                contentType: 'application/json',
                                data: auth,
                                processData: false,
                                success: function(data) {
                                    console.log(data)
                                },
                                dataType: 'json'
                            });
```